# exclude specific sub-type while using isSubTypeOf

Tags: byte-buddy

I am trying to exclude specific subType of an interface using below expression. The CompositeAction extends Action interface. And there are other interfaces that extend Action interface. I want to include all sub types of Action interface except the classes that implement CompositeAction interface. I tried with below expression but its not excluded.

```
isSubTypeOf(Action.class)
    .and(not(isSubTypeOf(named(CompositeAction.class.getName()))));
```

Also tried hasSuperType in place of isSubTypeOf, but that didn't work as well. Is it doable? Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

It should be as easy as:

```
isSubTypeOf(Action.class).and(not(isSubTypeOf(CompositeAction.class)))
```

In return, you get an `ElementMatcher` that you can supply a type to rather easily such that you can unit test this properly.